# How to get validator error or cannot add product to cart

Tags: php, javascript, validation

I'm using Magento 1.9 (CE) and I cant add the product to cart due to validator error. There's no message, it just returns false. If I'll try to submit the form with product manually it'll add to cart.

hidden input with form key exists on the product page.

the issue is not with cookies.

Comment: the issue was with hiddent input field. There's module allowing to notify the customer about product is in stock ( if it's currently is out of stock ). Module created block on page with input for email. That input doen't passed validation and error message doesn't displayed to to block was hidden